# Convert common sql column value to xml node

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2012

Let's say I have a data set like this:

```
|Group|Value|
|-----|-----|
|  A  | 123 |
|-----|-----|
|  A  | 234 |
|-----|-----|
|  B  | 123 |
|-----|-----|
```

And want to convert it into XML like this:

```
<Groups>
    <Group Name="A">
         <Values>
              <Value>123</Value>
              <Value>234</Value>   
         </Values> 
    </Group>  
    <Group Name="B">
         <Values>
              <Value>123</Value>
         </Values> 
    </Group>    
</Groups>
```

I've tried using something along the lines of:

```
   SELECT  
         [Group] AS "@Name"
        ,[Value] AS "Group/Values/Value"
    FROM [Tablename]
    FOR XML PATH('Group'), ROOT('Groups')
```

But what I'm getting is:

```
<Groups>
    <Group Name="A">
         <Values>
              <Value>123</Value> 
         </Values> 
    </Group>  
    <Group Name="A">
         <Values>
              <Value>234</Value>   
         </Values> 
    </Group>  
    <Group Name="B">
         <Values>
              <Value>123</Value>
         </Values> 
    </Group>    
</Groups>
```

How can I combine these nodes based on the data in the first column?

Comment: You need to group by group name

Comment: Adding GROUP BY [Group], [Value] didn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE([Group] VARCHAR(10), Value INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
('A',123),
('A',234),
('B',123)
```

### Query

```
SELECT   t.[Group] AS [@Name]

      ,(SELECT [Value] AS [Value]
        FROM @TABLE
        WHERE [Group] = t.[Group]
        FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Values') ,TYPE)
FROM @TABLE t
GROUP BY t.[Group]
FOR XML PATH('Group'), ROOT('Groups')
```

### Result

```
<Groups>
  <Group Name="A">
        <Values>
              <Value>123</Value>
              <Value>234</Value>
        </Values>
  </Group>
  <Group Name="B">
        <Values>
             <Value>123</Value>
        </Values>
  </Group>
</Groups>
```